# how concat a Value to its key in C++

Tags: c++, string

I don't know how to write my problem down but ill do my best.

say im using the C++ language :

i'd like to get the next result:

```
#include<iostream>
std::string line = "";
int lemmas = 1;
int main() {
    line = "<b>Lemma %d. <b>\n"; // i want line = <b>Lemma 1. <b>\n
    return 1;
}
```

how do i add its value (lemmas in my case)?

Comment: Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to construct the string using the `operator<<()`.

Comment: in C `printf` family will accept a string containing %d as format. So you can obviously do a `sprintf(buffer, line, lemmas);` if `buffer` is a large enough `char*`. Look at `snprintf` for securing length.

Comment: @hexasoft Well, the question clearly asks for a c++ solution.

Comment: In C you use `sprintf` *(sprintf_s for size safety)*. In C++ use streams or replicate the C functionality with C++ strings. Like `resize(expected length)`, use `&front()` and `sprintf` there. :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: well yes. Whatever `snprintf` is usable too in C :)

Comment: If you're using C++11, you can use `std::to_string(lemmas)` to convert `lemmas` to a string. Then use string concatenation for the rest.

Comment: @Ferruccio This should probably be another answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, the [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) class can be used to construct the string you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
std::string line = "";
int lemmas = 1;
int main() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "<b>Lemma " << lemmas << ". <b>\n"; // i want line = <b>Lemma 1. <b>\nnn
    line = oss.str();
    return 1;
}
```

C++ output doesn't use formatting clauses (e.g `%d`) like the c `printf()`function family.

Comment: and how do i clean the buffer?

Comment: @dan You can use another one, or use the move [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/operator%3DD): `oss = std:ostringstream;`.

Comment: oss.str(""); => cleaning the buffer:)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++11, you can use `std::to_string` to convert `lemmas` to a string.

```
#include<string>

std::string line = "";
int lemmas = 1;
int main() {
    line = "<b>Lemma " + std::to_string(lemmas) + ". <b>\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Alternatively, if Boost is available, you can do something much like your original code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

std::string line = "";
int lemmas = 1;
int main() {
    line = (boost::format("<b>Lemma %1%. <b>\n") % lemmas).str();
    return 1;
}
```